# Expected value of nearest distance between random uniform variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have $X_1,...,X_N$ independent random variables, with $X_i \sim U([0,1])$ $\forall i$.
I'm trying to answer the following question, informally speaking: suppose I am in $X_i$, what is the mininum distance I should travel in order to find the nearest $X_j$, for some $j$ ?

I formalised in the following way: find $\mathbb{E}[D_i]$, $D_i=\min_{j\neq i}\left \{ | X_i - X_j | \right \}$.

Now, doing some computations with $i\neq j$ we have that $Y_{ij}=| X_i - X_j |$ is continuous with probability density $f_{Y_{ij}}(y)=2(1-y)\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(y)$.

To compute $\mathbb{E}[D_i]$ one could compute $\mathbb{P}(D_i\geq d)=\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j\neq i}\{Y_{ij}\geq d\})$.

And here come the problems, since the variables $Y_{ij}$ (for a chosen $i$ and $j\neq i $) should not be independent (?).

So, anybody could help me from here? Maybe something clever with characteristic functions? Furthermore, is the problem correctly formalised?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Could we consider only $D_i = \underset{j}{\min}\{D_{i,j}\}$ where $D_{i,j}  = \underset{j<i}{\min}\{|X_i-X_j|\}$? It might be useful since $D_{i,1}, D_{i,2},\ldots$ are independent..

Answer (score 0):

An outline that may possibly help is the following.

1. For $i=2,\ldots,N$,  let $D_{i,j} = \underset{j<i}{\min}\{|X_i-X_j|\}$ since $(\forall i\neq j),\,|X_i - X_j| = |X_j - X_i|$. It follows that, $D_j = D_{(j+1,\,j)}$ where $D_{(k,j)}$ is the $k$-th order statistic of the set $\{D_{j+1,\,j},D_{j+2,\,j},\ldots,D_{N,\,j}\}$.
2. Since $\{D_{i,\,2}\}_{i=3}^{N}, \{D_{i,\,3}\}_{i=4}^{N},\ldots,\{D_{i,\,N}\}_{i=N-1}^{N}$ are independent sets, it follows that $\mathcal{D}_{N-1} = \{D_{1}, D_{2},\ldots, D_{N-1}\}$ form a collection of independent random variables.
3. If we could show that the elements of $\mathcal{D}_{N-1}$ are all identically distributed say by $f_{\mathcal{D}_{N-1}}(t)$, then it immediately follows that $\mathbb{E}[D_i] = \mathbb{E}[D_1]$ with expectation taken with respect to $f_{\mathcal{D}_{N-1}}(t)$.
4. If the elements of $\mathcal{D}_{N-1}$ are not identically distributed, then we obtain the joint $f_{\mathcal{D}_{N-1}}(d_1,\ldots,d_{N-1}) = \prod_{i=1}^{N-1}f_{D_i}(d_i)$. The value of $\mathbb{E}[D_i]$ is the corresponding marginal expectation with respect to $f_{D_i}(d_i)$.

Comment: is that right?  We could have $X_(n)$ closer to $X_(n-1)$ than $X_(n+1)$.

Comment: Oh i see i seem to get your point. Let me make some amends.

Comment: @dm63, I apologize. All I can muster is a possible outline considering all possible given information that might help.

Comment: intuitively it seems that the extremes are (a) all the points are spaced equally and hence the distance to nearest neighbor is 1/(N+1) and (2) the points are all bunched together such that the average distance to nearest neighbor can approach zero.  Evidently the answer is in between.